# Any database recommendation for handling large amount of timeseries data with microsecond precision on the timestamps?

Tags: database, timestamp, time-series, mapr, nosql

I'm looking for a suitable database for storing large amounts of timeseries data, and that supports microsecond timestamps. Any recommendations?

It would be nice if a suitable database technology can work together with my MapR cluster. I've checked out OpenTSDB, but the problem is that it only supports storing timestamps with millisecond precision.

Hope to hear from you :-)

Best regards, Julianne.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, OpenTSDB today only support timestamps to the millisecond (ms) level.

The OpenTSDB project has an enhancement request open: https://github.com/OpenTSDB/opentsdb/issues/846

Depending of your requirements (number of metrics, aggregations, queries and vizualization tools) you can build your own data model using MapR-DB if you are using it already.

The idea would be to use the same rowkey/_id pattern that you have in OpenTSDB (metrics+timestamp+tags to make is simple), and store the values into the documents,and you can capture the data with MapR-Streams/Kafka and keep this as your "raw data" and use the DB to store aggregations in documents using for example Apache Spark

Once again it will also depend a lot of the way you want to "consume" these data.